# POCO 1.12.1 NET project does not compile in VS 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, poco

The new POCO library version 1.12.1 NET project does not compile in Visual Studio 2022, it does not even load the project. I had to set the Visual Studio version in the project properties from 2019 to 2022 simply to be able to open it. But it does not compile!

Eduardo Quintana

Comment: The x64 'Net' project in Poco version 1.12.2 still does not compile in Visual Studio 2022. I am still using 1.11.x!

Comment: Nobody seems to care but version 1.12.x is useless for us who use Visual Studio 2022!!!